# Why do my clothes not save in GTA V online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Everything was working fine. I was able to change clothes anytime and it would save. Now, all of a sudden, every time I die or change servers my clothes reset to the outfit I had purchased at the start. I would love to create and keep my own look, any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also often experienced the same problem and did look into it as although it never causes too much of a hassle to simply change them back, it can be boring after so many times.

Unfortunately I found there is no way of permanently keeping the same clothes on as to make the game more realistic, Rockstar incorporated the idea that over time your characters change clothes when unattended as they would in the real world. My ONLY option for you is to select the clothes you wish to wear online in a store rather than in your home wardrobe, I believe this improves how often this occurs and is fairly easy to deal with as whilst online, all clothes are available from the same store.

Hope this helps, enjoy your killing sprees.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help! please feel free to inform me if this method still hasn't solved the problem, i'll do my best to help!

Comment: Hmm it seems to still not save unfortunatly. Its a shame haha!

Comment: My only other option to ask you is whether you are saving your game manually before you leave the session or go offline or whether you just leave it to the nearest autosave, this is honestly the only other option I could recommend that may solve this problem :/